# Getting error "duplicate key value violates unique constraint postgres"

Tags: postgresql

I have table like this:

```
p_id | store |      createdat      | device  | deviceserial | application
------+-------+---------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 08:02:39 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 08:08:18 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 08:10:10 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 08:20:10 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 10:40:11 | IOS     | 6625839827   | app-b
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 10:45:11 | IOS     | 6625839827   | app-b
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 10:50:11 | IOS     | 6625839827   | app-b
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 08:47:10 | Android | 636363636891 | app-a
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 08:55:10 | Android | 636363636891 | app-a
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 08:59:10 | Android | 636363636891 | app-a
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 13:01:11 | IOS     | 6625839828   | app-b
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 13:15:11 | IOS     | 6625839828   | app-b
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 12:03:10 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 12:09:10 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 12:12:10 | Android | 636363636890 | app-a
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 15:15:11 | IOS     | 6625839827   | app-b
      | z10   | 2020-09-02 15:20:11 | IOS     | 6625839827   | app-b
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 10:25:10 | Android | 636363636891 | app-a
      | z11   | 2020-09-02 10:35:10 | Android | 636363636891 | app-a
```

I am trying to insert some queries to another table(device_usage_test1).Thats my table:

```
create table if not exists device_usage_test1(id SERIAL,deviceserial VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,device VARCHAR(50),deviceusage DOUBLE PRECISION)
```

And this is my insert command :

```
insert into device_usage_test1(deviceserial,device,deviceusage) select deviceserial,device,sum(deviceusage) as deviceusage
from (
    select deviceserial,device,
         
     extract(epoch from (max(createdat)::timestamp - min(createdat)::timestamp)) as deviceusage,
     date_trunc('hour', createdat) +
     (((date_part('minute', createdat)::integer / 10::integer) * 10::integer)|| ' minutes')::interval AS hr
    FROM datatable  
    group by deviceserial,hr,device
) t
group by deviceserial,device;
```

Later I will make upsert query on device_usage_test1.So my deviceserial have to be unique.
But when I try the insert with deviceserial (unique).It gives me error:
`ERROR:duplicate key value violates unique constraint "device_usage_deviceserial_key""`

`DETAIL: Key (deviceserial)=(636363636890) already exists.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a data issue. Your select is returning at least 2 devices with the same deviceserail (1004573GT7). Try running the following:

```
select * 
  from (select deviceserial
              ,device       
              ,extract(epoch from (max(createdat)::timestamp - min(createdat)::timestamp)) as deviceusage
              ,date_trunc('hour', createdat) +
               (((date_part('minute', createdat)::integer / 10::integer) * 10::integer)|| ' minutes')::interval AS hr
         from datatable where createdat > now() - interval '1 day' 
        group by deviceserial,hr,device
       ) s
having count(deviceserial)>1
order by deviceserial;
```

NOTE: No table definitions nor sample data given , above not tested.

---

Second:  
You **can not** have a unique constraint deviceserail and at the same time have multiple devices for a deviceserail. Having multiple devices per deviceserail is by definition not unique on deviceserail. You can instead define your unique key on both (deviceserail,device).

```
drop table device_usage_test1; 
create table device_usage_test1(id serial
                               ,deviceserial varchar(50) 
                               ,device varchar(50)
                               ,deviceusage double precision
                               ,constraint device_usage_test1_pk 
                                           primary key (id)
                               ,constraint device_usage_test1_bk
                                           unique (deviceserial,device)
                               );
```

However, this allows your initial bad data having both "android" and "Android" to co-exist. you may want to restrict capitalization on device. For example:

```
alter table device_usage_test1
        add constraint device_initcap_check 
            check (device = initcap(device));
```

Comment: Thank you,@Belayer Your query is giving me error.I added sample data.

Comment: Saying it is  gives an error is useless. What Error! But in this case that is not necessary. The first 2 rows of your sample data is sufficient to detect the initial error. You group by  deviceserial,device but have a unique constraint on deviceserial. Since "android" does not equal "Android"  you have 2 groups with deviceserial 636363636890. Thus violating the unique constraint. It would seem you have 2 options: #1 **and perfered** clean-up your data; #2 just group by deviceserial; #3 group by deviceserial, initcap(device) - however it is unpredictable as to which device is choose.

Comment: Thanks,@Belayer.Somehow I did not notice it.Its working now with sample data.But in real  data there is not such issue of capital and small letter.If I remove device from my query and groupby with deviceSerial, it give successful result.But If i add device in my query ,it gives me error.But I need device column value from corresponding deviceSerial.I am pretty new to Postgres.Any idea,how can I select device without putting it in groupby.

Comment: See revised answer. It changes the unique key.

Comment: Thank you @Belayer.It worked perfectly .Thats a big help.If I want to update the table  with upsert query Postgres which constraint,should I target?On conflict (deviceserial, device)?.This table (device_usage_test1)will update everyday with different time(createdAt).